# WordPress Rest API Simultaneous Request Limit

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I have an idea for a website which would allow users to register, then create and edit their own individual pages using the WordPress Rest API through the front-end.

I was wondering what the limitations are if there are multiple requests sent to the WordPress Rest API at the exact same time, ex. 1000 to 100,000 users are logged in and updating their pages at once.

I'm assuming that wordpress.com is using the Rest API extensively and could easily handle millions of requests at once, but i'm not sure.

Any ideas?